# Calling a web service that uses session state in wcf

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services, session

I have a web service that calls another web service that uses session state.  Now I am rewriting the web service and making it WCF.  I am having some confusion on how to call my web service from my wcf service.

Here is the code as it exists now:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true]
public string MyWebServiceCall()
{
   string result;
   MyOtherWebService.MyOtherWebService C = 
                                new MyOtherWebService.MyOtherWebService();
   C.CookieContainer = GetCookieContainer();
   result = C.GetResult();
   Session[_codingBookSession] = C.CookieContainer;
   return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can find information about working with sessions in WCF in this MSDN article:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733040.aspx

> In Windows Communication Foundation
>   (WCF) applications, a session
>   correlates a group of messages into a
>   conversation. **WCF sessions are
>   different than the session object
>   available in ASP.NET applications**,
>   support different behaviors, and are
>   controlled in different ways. This
>   topic describes the features that
>   sessions enable in WCF applications
>   and how to use them.

Comment: is it possible to show me what the code would look like to replace the method listed?